# How can I combine these sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-combination

I am having following constructions

> 1. my supervisor strongly recommend for an extension.
> 2. I would like to apply for one year extension period.
> 3. I have been granted a scholarship.

Would the following sentence be a way to write the previous sentence in a single sentence?

> Therefore, with my supervisor's strong recommendation, I would like to apply for one year extension period for my scholarship that I have been granted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you beginning your sentence with *Therefore*? I would just write the sentence thus:

> **Given** my supervisor’s strong recommendation, I would like to apply for one year extension period for my scholarship.

It is not necessary to state that the scholarship has been granted - the word extension already indicates this.

Answer (score 5):

It is a little wordy

> Therefore, with my supervisor’s strong recommendation, I would like to apply for a one year extension of my scholarship.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to apply for one  year extension of my scholarship as my supervisor recommends it.